# How to generate a modular directory structure with Zend_Tool?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

The only examples I've seen of generating a Zend Framework project with Zend_Tool create this directory structure:

/application/controllers 
/application/models 
/application/views

Does Zend_Tool have the ability to generate a **modular** directory structure (where each module has its own models, views, and controllers)?

example:

/application/modules/default/controllers 
/application/modules/default/models 
/application/modules/default/views

/application/modules/admin/controllers 
/application/modules/admin/models 
/application/modules/admin/views

Answer (score 1):

You should probably ask this question on the Zend Framework development mailing lists.  `Zend_Tool` is available only in the ZF 1.8 Preview Release currently, and it is still under active development.  Large pieces of the documentation for `Zend_Tool` are still unwritten.

You can also ask on the Yahoo group for Zend Tool:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/zf-tool/

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Tool got updates on creating modules. Zend Framework 1.8.1 comes with module creation support, but still needs some improvements.